# bash tail & watch

Tags: bash

I have a app server that I start and it writes output to stdout.  I want to be able to watch that output and issue a command (in this case growlnotify -m "Server is up") when a specific line is sent to stdout, but I still want the all the output go to stdout.

Note I'd rather not write to a file

Comment: Note: I **think** (you should test this) on UNIX/Linux/MacOSX that if you decide at some point to kill the notifier app, since you're notified, you'd kill your server as well (unless you ignore SIGPIPE). So you'd need to keep it running or lose your server.

Comment: in the case of growl it's just sending an async message to a bg process that shows the notification on screen.  You don't generally kill it but I have tested with the accepted answer and dismissing the message works fine without killing the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output of the server command to a while loop:

```
server | while read; do if [[ $REPLY =~ "Server is up" ]]; then
    # do something
  fi
  echo "$REPLY"
done
```

Comment: You can have the server running in the background, writing to a log file. Then `tail -f logfile | while read; do ...; done`, using the same `while` loop as in the answer.

Comment: i always want the server in the foreground in this case so ctrl+c will stop it also don't want log files

Comment: And we have a winner! this worked perfectly.